# calling fetch, data won't return, not sure why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

I'm trying to do a simple fetch to return some data to be visualised.

The fetch looks like this,

```
import firebase from './firebase';

export async function apiRequest(path, method = 'GET', data) {
  const accessToken = firebase.auth().currentUser
    ? await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
    : undefined;

  return fetch(`/api/${path}`, {
    method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : undefined,
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(path,response);
      if (response.status === 'error') {
        // Automatically signout user if accessToken is no longer valid
        if (response.code === 'auth/invalid-user-token') {
          firebase.auth().signOut();
        }

        throw new CustomError(response.code, response.message);
      } else {
        console.log('success')
        return response.data;
      }
    });
}

// Create an Error with custom message and code
export function CustomError(code, message) {
  const error = new Error(message);
  error.code = code;
  return error;
}

// Check if a indexDb database exists
export function indexedDbdatabaseExists(dbname, callback) {
  const req = window.indexedDB.open(dbname);
  let existed = true;
  req.onsuccess = function () {
    req.result.close();
    if (!existed) window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(dbname);
    callback(existed);
  };
  req.onupgradeneeded = function () {
    existed = false;
    callback(existed);
  };
}
```

On running this function in my react component like this,

```
export default function useHome() {
  
  ....
  const { data: settingsData } = useSWR(
    'dashboard/get-settings',
    apiRequest);
  console.log("does it load settings",settingsData);
  ...

 ...

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    handleCalendarClick(selectedDate);
  }, [selectedDate]);

  return {
   ...
    settingsData,
  };
}
```

It does show in the console that it loads, but when taking that settings data into a parent component,

```
export function Home() {
  const {
   ....
    settingsData,
  } = useHome();
console.log("home settings",settingsData)
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      ..
      <div>
        <Overview data={lineGraphData} timing={settingsData} />
      </div>
      ..
    </div>
  );
}
```

It doesn't resolve - it either says promise completed in console, or that there is nothing to be returned.

This is useSWR

```
https://swr.vercel.app/
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `useSWR`?

Comment: The way you return the promise from your async function is really strange. Are you trying to return the final JSON? If so consider using the await syntax in your whole function. So await fetch do your checks then await JSON then return the parsed json

Comment: Your also doing your checks on the body JSON not the response object

Comment: @Jazz returning the `.then()` chain will work fine; it's a Promise that will resolve to the object; also it seems OP is checking their own server response, which is also basically fine. I don't think any of this is the issue; the question is how does `useSWR` look. Flagging this as "needs debugging details" now.

Comment: THanks guys. Happy to chainge the structure of teh code

Comment: I think @ChrisG is right the promise chain should work, moving it to a single syntax would make it more readable though. Can you show the full console logs for this? on the link it says that you can also get an error output from the useSWR hook, can you log that too?

Comment: It looks like @Jazz was indeed on the right track, but we won't know until you confirm this, OP. `fetch`, unlike axios, does not use a `.data` property. So unless that is part of your server response (and we have no idea what it looks like), you're returning `undefined`. Using `response => response.json()` is done to grab the actual data sent back by the server, so the question is: does your API use `.status` and `.code` and `.data` in its reply like I optimistically assumed? Or are you indeed accessing non-existent properties there?